# Select data between hour by hour basis

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, between

I am using postgresql, My idea is to select the data which are created before 24 hour, which I retrieved using the following

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE created < now() - '24 hours'::interval
```

In this I tried to add a condition Which brings the data between the hour basis using the BETWEEN clause, for this my query is following

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE created < now() - '24 hours'::interval 
AND created BETWEEN {condition} AND {condition}
```

My *created* column is in timestamp with timezone, When I tried to use

> extract(hour from created)

in the condition, I am not getting any results. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is being bound to the `{condition}` placeholders?

Comment: extract(hour from created) - 1  and extract(hour from created) to check the data between the hour

Comment: You need to compare `EXTRACT(hour from created)` on the LHS to hour values on the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check hourly ranges which occurred outside the last 24 hours, then use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable 
WHERE created <  now() - '24 hours'::interval AND
    EXTRACT(hour from created) >= 10 AND EXTRACT(hour from created) < 11;
```

This would find all records outside of the last 24 hours whose hour is between 10 and 11am.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, I want to select data outside of first '24 hours'. Sorry, I updated the query.